# Reagent app behind an Apache proxy does not render

Tags: apache, proxy, jetty, clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to run a Reagent Web app behind an Apache proxy to forward the HTTPS to the HTTP Jetty server running the Reagent app behind it. Here are the Apache rules:

```
ProxyPass /bookmarx http://localhost:3000
ProxyPassReverse /bookmarx http://localhost:3000
```

The app runs fine when I run it locally, i.e. http:// localhost:3000. However, when I run the app through the Apache server, e.g. https:// example.com/bookmarx, it simply returns the HTML start page (i.e. the one with the code snippet below) and does not execute the Javascript (core/init!) so all I see is a blank page.

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Interestingly, I can call the Clojure service behind it, e.g. https://example.com/bookmarx/api/bookmarks and it returns the bookmarks, so I know that the proxy is forwarding the requests but the ClojureScript isn't running.

I played around with rewrite rules and x-forwarded-proto headers and that didn't seem to make any difference.

I also get the same results if I configure the Apache server to run it using HTTP rather than HTTPS, so I know that it's not the SSL interfering.

What do I need to do to get the app running through the proxy?

Comment: Thinking about this some more I'm starting to wonder if my problem is related to the fact that the page is using core.async to call the server to load the bookmarks before rendering. When I go directly to the localhost jetty server, it blocks until the results are returned. But when I go through the proxy, it doesn't block and tries to render the page before the results are returned. I'm not sure off hand how to fix this, if that indeed is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked down the problem. It was a result of having the routes in secretary/account wrong. It was looking for a route of "/", which is correct when local, but the remote URL had "/bookmarx/". So when I changed the route to "/bookmarx/" it worked fine. I guess I was assuming that Apache was re-writing the URL when passing it.

(It took quite a bit of process-of-elimination backtracking to figure out this innocuously simple answer. With hindsight, I could have posted the code straightaway then perhaps another set of eyes would have seen it. Lessons learned. Thanks for everyone's help.)

Answer (score 1):

In principle HTTPS should not matter here, the only important things are can the browser get the assets (HTML+javascript files), and is the javascript correct.

The first thing to do is open your browser developer console (view->developer->javascript console) and look for errors. Check the network tab to be sure that the javascript file loaded... another way to check that the javascript loaded is to view the source of the HTML and click or open the link to the javascript included.

Here are some things to check:

1. Is js/app.js loaded? Try navigating to https://example.com/js/app.js (where the root for your index page matches the root for js). Sometimes the assets are served out of a different route when deployed to a host due to configuration.
2. Is your deployed app.js built using optimizations advanced compilation? Things can go wrong! Try replacing `advanced` with `whitespace` in your deploy build to rule this out. If this is the problem, you are probably missing some javascript externs. Note that if you are deploying a dev build, you would need to deploy the out compilation files as well. You can test production builds locally with `lein cljsbuild once prod` if you have a build called prod.
3. Are there any errors reported in the javascript console? There can be good clues here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 
1. I am able to load js/app.js and the js console shows it loaded when I try to open the page as well.
2. I tried :whitespace and unfortunately it made no difference.
3. The errors in the js console that I am seeing when I go through the Apache proxy are:

`Error rendering component (in bookmarx.route.current_page)
Error: Assert failed: Invalid Hiccup form: [nil]
 (in bookmarx.route.current_page)
(valid-tag? tag)`

I'm not sure what it wouldn't be able render due it to going through the proxy.

Comment: are you able to post some code? It looks like somewhere you have a component that is conditionally specifying a tag, but the condition is empty, eg: `[(when condition :div) "ok"]` which is in the context you are running it false. I'd look at all component references to check that you don't have a case where they could be missing.

Answer (score 0):

With the same issue I just put in more rules until the problem went away. This is the one I used for the problem I was having with the /api:

```
ProxyPassReverse /api http://0.0.0.0:3001/api
ProxyPass /api http://0.0.0.0:3001/api
```

I am using Untangled, which is more of a framework than a library. So when the Chrome developer console told me about the error - that was actually the first time I realised there even was an `/api`.

Comment: Fortunately, I don't have a problem with the /api. It consistently returns results like it should, even though the page isn't rendering.